# Log in Request Failed

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, login

On the Stack Exchange iOS app version 1.6.6.2, iOS 9.3.5 (old, I know, but it's the highest I can upgrade my iPhone 4s to), I am getting this error repeatedly when trying to log in with Google.

[image: Log in Request Failed]

I just updated the iOS app, so version 1.6.6.2 seems to be the latest supported on the highest version of iOS my phone will support.

Comment: Do you have other OpenID providers linked to your account?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, I don't. I was able to work around this by creating a stack exchange account and logging in that way though.